# how to handle reference to array after data fetch on react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

The code below its a simple useEffect that runs code for change in variable **channel**
After the result of a async function completes.
When the variable is seted, I simple can't reach : `channelResult.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads` because he brokes on array access...

so, I can do: `channelResult.result` `result: {}`

I can do: `channelResult.result.items` `result: [{}]`

but not: `channelResult.result.items[0]` `result: error`

```
  export default function YoutubeForm() {
  const [ytId, setYtId] = useState("");
  const [checked, setCheck] = useState(false);

  const [channel, setChannel] = useState({ result: {} });
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState("");

  const channelId = "UCwZmL_QQEnAerrgCDm5pV-Q";

  

useEffect(() => {
    let items = channel.result.items; // result: [{...}]
    let items = channel.result.items[0]; // result: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

    // setUpload(channelResult.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
  }, [channel]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(upload);
  }, [upload]);

  const handleYtIdOnChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    // debounce effect
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(() => setYtId(value), 1000);
  };
// this function fire when user press a button, 
// the function resolves a get from youtube 
// server and sets its value on useState of setChannel
  const checkYdId = () => {
    return getChannelUploads(channelId).then((res) => setChannel(res));
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Youtube
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="center">
          <TextField
            required
            id="cardName"
            label="ID do canal"
            onChange={handleYtIdOnChange}
            value={channelId}
          />
          <Button color="primary" variant="outlined" onClick={checkYdId}>
            Check
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        <div style={{ maxHeight: "300px", width: "100%", overflow: "scroll" }}>
          <Grid item>{checked ? <List /> : null}</Grid>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

how to handle that reference access?

Comment: The question's unclear... Can you provide more context and more code?

Comment: @SakoBu edited to complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

just the code below in the useEffect

```
if (items instanceof Array) {
      setUpload(items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads);
    }
```